# Writing Dataframe to hive external location taking too long time

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm runing the spark job with below configuration parameters.

```
--deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 20g \
  --executor-memory 25g \
  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=6000  \
  --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2000 \
  --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2000 --num-executors 5
```

I am trying to write the dataframe to hive external location as below. I'm working on spark 1.6 and Apache Hadoop 2.x

```
dataFrame.repartition(50)
  .write().mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .partitionBy(ISL_CAR.asof.name())
  .saveAsTable(dbName + "." + tableName);
```

While running this, it's taking long time to write into hive external location. I found the link 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/append-slow-with-spark-2.0.0.html, where they are explained about similar the issue, but the difference is explanation is for Spark 2 and S3 data load (we are facing the issue in Spark 1.6 and write into hive external location). Will this config work for Spark 1.6 version as well?

Suggestion from the above link is to set the configuration as:

```
dataset.write.option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
```

Any suggestion on how to improve the code to write in parallel to hive external location.